# Dehydrating Apple Cider Vinegar?

Tags: vinegar, apples

Someone at Alcohol SE suggested that I post this question here: Dehydrating Apple Cider Vinegar?

I've been experimenting with dehydrating apple cider vinegar

I'd like to concentrate it and put it into capsules. ~15 size 00 capsules are needed to contain 1 tbsp of apple cider vinegar. Since most apple cider vinegar purchased on the market is ~95% water, the result of putting it into gelatin capsules is that  the capsules dissolve. In theory, I should be able to separate out the water and be left with a substance that will not dissolve capsules made for oils. Also in theory, I could make 1 serving of apple cider vinegar fit into 1 capsule and have some room left over.

My current method is to dehydrate the apple cider vinegar at 145 degrees fahrenheit. I've ready that any temperature higher than 150 farenheit will break down enzymes in whatever substance I'm heating (I'm assuming there are precious enzymes to preserve in apple cider vinegar). The result after 3 hours is a brown syrupy substance that only partially dissolved a gelatin capsule. The result after 6 hours is a thick dark brown substance that I'm currently testing in gelatin capsules. My questions is, is it safe to assume that that dark brown substance is dehydrated apple cider vinegar that can be rehydrated, or would the dehyration process evaporate the vinegar away along with the water?

What might this left over substance be, in that case?

Comment: This post is originally from Chemistry SE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91412/dehydrating-apple-cider-vinegar
Most recently posted in Alcohol SE: https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/dehydrating-apple-cider-vinegar#autocomment5426

Comment: Most of the 5% that's not water is [acetic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetic_acid#Properties). That has a melting point just below room temperature, so should easily solidify in the fridge.  Of course in practice you'll evaporate some unknown amount of the acetic acid as well. But *why* are you doing this? Is it actually for food or some strange dietary supplement? Concentrated acetic acid is rather corrosive and I wouldn't want it in my mouth if the capsule just about holds together until you take it.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable here, and if it's about making supplements rather than food that would seem to be a health question and therefore off-topic.  I'm holding off a close vote to allow clarification of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's currently open in an identical form on Chemistry.SE. Please don't post identical questions on multiple sites.

Comment: Andrew, I see you were just following the advice you got on our sister sites when you posted your question on multiple sites. Unfortunately, the advice was not ideal, as cross-posting is frowned upon. Ideally, you’d check each site’s help center (ours: [help]) and decide which is the best fit. You may also ask about different aspects on different sites, if applicable.

Comment: @Catija Unfortunately, this user was basically *told* to go post in other places, and no one bothered to warn them about cross-posting.

Comment: Let's keep this here. I've let chemistry mods know they can close it if they'd like to prevent multiple posting, but it's fine here.

Answer (score 5):

You might actually want to look at other methods - either alongside or instead of your current dehydration.

"Commercial" Vinegar powder (where it isn't actually just the acid components) is basically maltodextrin  sprayed with your vinegar and dried. There's [a ton of references](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=maltoodextrin%20apple%20cider%20vinigar&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=ificWuiUApSSvQTApZqIAg) like this [one](https://www.spiceography.com/vinegar-powder/), though admittedly I learnt this from watching how its made.

The nice thing here is you don't really need more heat (or high heat) to do this.  In theory you might also be able to do it with starch.

Since the water is 'locked away' its also less likely to dissolve your capsule

I'm almost half certain that I remember that spray drying or freeze drying would work too, but I can't find any sources, and these arn't processes one can easily do at home